# Derby EmbeddedDriver working without Class.forName

Tags: java, derby

The documentation tells us to load JDBC driver like so

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
```

https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html

But it works fine without and getting the connection straight away

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + pathDerby + ";create=true");
```

Why is that?

Version from the log: *Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.13.1.1 - (1765088)*

EDIT:

Actually it is needed if you shut down the Derby engine and want to open it again in the same JWM process (I do this all the time in my integration tests)

After shut down

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
```

You should reopen like this

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:" + pathDerby + ";create=true");
```

Comment: You could raise some jobs in the Derby issue tracker to remove/revise the obsolete documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry:
>
> my.sql.Driver
>
> **Applications no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName().** Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

Comment: @Stig: in my opinion this "shutdown connection" is an abuse of the `getConnection()` interface. Why would I _open_ a connection to _shutdown_ the database. The DriverManager was never intended to manage the lifecycle of the database (server)

Comment: agree, but this is how Derby is implemented. :)